# Python, Kivy - Set size of button relative to image size

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am making a game with Kivy. I would like to set the button size to half the size the image size.

This is my .kv

```
<HomeScreen>:
Image:
    source: "data/background.png"

    Button:
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        width: root.width / 1.5
        height: root.height / 7.5
        pos: (root.width / 2) - (self.width / 2), root.height - root.height * 0.4

        on_press: app.change("PlayScreen") # change screen function

        Image:
            pos: self.parent.x, self.parent.y
            width: self.parent.width
            height: self.parent.height

            source: "data/button.png"

            Label:
                pos: self.parent.center_x - (self.width / 2), (self.parent.height / 2) - (self.height / 2.25) + self.parent.y

                color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                font_size: self.parent.height / 3
                text: "Play"
```

This is my Python:

```
class handler(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Builder.load_file("data/layouts.kv")
        self.sm = getSM()
        self.places = {0: "HomeScreen"}

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):

        Window.size = (1000, 800)
        Window.minimum_width, Window.minimum_height = Window.size
        self.title = "Digital Drummer"

        return self.sm

    def change(self, to):
        print(self.root.children[0].children[0].size)

        if to == "Back":
            print("Changing from " + self.sm.current + " to " + self.places[len(self.places) - 2])

            self.root.transition = FadeTransition(duration=0.5)

            self.sm.current = self.places[len(self.places) - 2]
            del self.places[len(self.places) - 1]


        else:
            print("Changing from " + self.sm.current + " to " + to)

            self.root.transition = FadeTransition(duration=0.5)

            self.sm.current = to
            self.places[len(self.places)] = self.sm.current
```

When I resize it vertically then the button images get bigger and move upward as my background image moves down as it centres.

I tried having a function -

```
def getFrame(self):
    print(self.children[0].width, self.children[0].height)
    return self.children[0]
```

and running `root.getFrame()` but the sizes were just the window size, even though the image shown was not.

How can I get the size and position of the background image?

Comment: The `root` in your `kv` is the `HomeScreen`. If you want to refer to the `Image`, add an `id` to the `Image` rule, then you can refer to the `Image` `Widget` using that `id` in the `kv` instead of `root`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson OK. But if I do `id: frame` in the image and then in the `HomeScreen` class - `print(self.ids.frame)`, it just prints the window size not the image size.

Comment: Can't figure it out without seeing the code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson ok Ive done that

Comment: That is still not a [mcve]. I cannot reproduce the problem. The link provided says: "Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included in the question itself".